# how to triger change when input value updated by jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, input, detect

I'm adding value by clicking a button inside an iframe (same domain) to an input field located in parent.

i need to triger change on the input field after that, but i cant detect it since it happens by jquery and not manually + since it is done from iframe to parent...

here is the fiddle, but i can't realy simulate it in fiddle as iframe is involved...

`

```
<iframe id="someiframe">
<div id="container">
  <div id="thebutton" class="btn">
    <button>add value to input field</button>
  </div>
</div>
</iframe>


<input class="someclasss" type="text" name="somename" id="target" maxlength="8" value="">

<div id="check">if detected i will become yellow</div>

// passing the value by click
jQuery("#thebutton").click(function() {

  jQuery("#target").val("12345678");

  jQuery("#target").trigger('change');
});

// detecting value passing
jQuery("#target").on('change input paste', function() {

jQuery("#check").css("background", "yellow");
alert("OK - DETECTED CHANGE");
});

#check {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

`
    https://jsfiddle.net/ogasbo73/

Answer (score 0):

got it to work with:

```
parent.jQuery("#target").trigger('change');
```